# Obfuscation of android app

Tags: android, obfuscation, proguard, decompiling, deobfuscation

Is there any way to reverse engineering the ProGuard files? I wrote a program and want to obfuscation it, but I am worrying at the same time is there possible somebody clear it up?

Is it any application that obfuscation the android codes better than proguard? 
thanks for consideration.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Obfuscation gives you better protection against reverse engineering. It makes it harder for those decompiling your code to understand it.

That said, you should know there is no way to completely secure your app against decompilation. It is just a matter of how much time a person is willing to spend on cracking your app and how good he is.

If you want to protect the logic of the app you should probably move that code on a server and use api calls to exchange data between the app and the server.